# Deploy solution in sitecore commerce 10

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am working with `Sitecore commerce 10`, I have added PayPal payment gateway and some custom fields for sellable items in `customer.sample.solution`. Now I need to deploy this solution to my Sitecore commerce site. I do not know how to do this properly.

To deploy the custom sample solution  I used the below steps

1. publish the Sitecore commerce engine core application via the visual studio publish option.
2. select the publishing target as `wwwroot/commerce authoring`.
3. Change the `localhost:4200` URL with `bizfx.com`.

Is there anything I missed or did wrong ? and can anyone suggest the step-by-step ways to do this?

After publishing through visual studio, my business tool looks like bellow

[image]

Comment: This blog can help you - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-10-commerce-engine-custom-package-thai-nguyen/

Comment: Hi @GauravAgarwal, Thankyou for your response. as per https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/100/sitecore-experience-commerce/deploying-your-sitecore-xc-solution.html this official document, i published using visual studio publish option, select publishing target as commerceauthoring folder from wwwroot. and then i replace the localhost:4200 with bizfx.com  but now I am getting error while running the bizfx.is there anything I missed?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal  This is the error that I faced `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://commerceauthoring.scws.com/api/GetNavigationView()' from origin 'https://bizfx.scws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: please compare commerce json files before and after deployment

Comment: @GauravAgarwal  yes, now the error is gone but the business tool looks different. please refer above image

Comment: In content policy file check SitecoreConnectionPolicy, if the credentials to connect Sitecore is correct.